# Pass an object in to a thread in a loop each time in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm not an expert in vb.net so this is kind of a frustrating  problem for me. I need read images from a directory and process them parallely. SO ideally what my code should do is,

```
Dim Directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo("New Folder\\")
   Dim allFiles As IO.FileInfo() = Directory.GetFiles("*.bmp")
    Dim singleFile As IO.FileInfo
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each singleFile In allFiles
        Console.WriteLine(singleFile.FullName)

        If File.Exists(singleFile.FullName) Then
            Dim badge As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)        (singleFile.FullName)
            i = i + 1
            Dim checkLabelThread As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf processBadge(badge, i))
        End If
    Next`
```

Here, processBadge is the function that should process the badge. But Vb.net does not allow me to pass variables in to that function. Is there a work around to fix this and fulfill my requirement? Thanks a lot.

Comment: In order to make it compile (and assuming that your `Image(Of T1, T2)` is even a real type) you just need to change `AddressOf` to `Sub()`. This whole thing, however, needs a rethink: fire-and-forget threads inside a loop? Sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generally do this:

```
Dim checkLabelThread As Thread = New Thread(Sub() processBadge(badge, i))
```

Note the replacement of `AddressOf` with `Sub()`.

However, because you are threading the value of `i` will update before the thread executes so you'll never get the actual value of `i` - the loop will have finished so the value will be count of the items in the `allFiles` array.

So here's what I'd do.

First I'd create an overload of `processBadge` to make the calling code cleaner. Like this:

```
Private Sub processBadge(fileInfo As FileInfo, index As Integer)
    Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.FullName)
    If File.Exists(fileInfo.FullName) Then
        Dim badge As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = _
            New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(singleFile.FullName)
        processBadge(badge, index)
    End If
End Sub
```

Then I'd call it using `Parallel.ForEach` like this:

```
Dim source = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("New Folder\\") _
    .GetFiles("*.bmp") _
    .Select(Function(f, i) New With { .FileInfo = f, .Index = i })
Parallel.ForEach(source, Sub(x) processBadge(x.FileInfo, x.Index))
```

That won't create too many threads and should maximize the performance.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class to hold your thread context information (untested code follows):

```
Public Class BadgeProcessor
    Private ReadOnly _badge As Image
    Private ReadOnly _index As Integer
    Public Sub New(badge As Image, index As Integer)
        _badge = badge
        _index = index
    End Sub
    Public Sub ProcessBadge()
        ' do what your processBadge method does here
    End Sub
End Class
```

And use that in your loop:

```
If File.Exists(singleFile.FullName) Then
    Dim badge As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(singleFile.FullName)
    i = i + 1
    Dim bp As BadgeProcessor = New BadgeProcessor(badge, i)
    Dim checkLabelThread As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf bp.ProcessBadge)
    'checkLabelThread.Start() ?
End If
```

However, if you have 1000 images in the directory, you are going to start 1000 threads, which is probably not going to be what you want.  You should probably investigate the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which would use a thread pool to limit the concurrent threads to something more reasonable - perhaps a [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) loop.